# Can't change focus from lateral / top bar. Input sources unresponsive in main application area

Tags: touchpad

I have a HP Spectre x360 running Ubuntu 18.04.

I have this issue at least a few times per week in which I'm using some application normally when suddenly one of the icons from the side bar is dragged out of place. At this point the mouse pointer looks like a hand and I need to make sure to move the icon back to its original place and press ESC to release it.

When I'm lucky I can continue using the computer normally after that, but sometimes even after I press ESC I don't get the focus back. I can use the bar to open any of the applications, but I can't interact with them with keyboard, touchpad or touchscreen. The only way to fix it is to logout and start a new session.

I'd like to understand what is triggering it (maybe some weird gesture in the touchpad?) and if there is a way to fix it that wouldn't require logging out and closing everything.